# How do I upload audio files to Azure and convert them to words?

Tags: azure

I haven't used Azure in ages, and the interface is new.   I can't find a forum for Azure users either.   My question is this - I have some audio files, and I'd like to use an automated Azure service that makes a transcript out of them.

Can anyone point me to instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Speech to Text (Cognitive Services) + the sdk of your favorite programming language.

You can find more information in the following links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-to-text

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk